# How to make this recursive function more FP-like?

Tags: scala, performance

The question is, given the sequence `S` (|S| > 5) of integers (can be Array, List or whatever you want), break down this sequence into 3 **non-empty** sequences that has the least cost.

- What are the costs? the corresponding element of the sequence. for instance:

```
[5, 3, 8, 2, 10932, 4, 1, 87, 1]
               ^
    The cost of breaking on this element would be 10932
And the solution to this problem would be:
[5, 3, 8] [10932, 4] [87, 1] -> cost = 2 + 1 = 3
         ^         ^          
These values are omitted as the costs
```

Obviously some implicit rules that should be considered are:

- 1. We need 2 breakpoints
- 2. We should not break on the first and the last element
- 3. We should not break on 2 adjacent elements, because it results into an empty seq

So this is the implementation I've come up with:

```scala
@tailrec
  def calculateCost(arr: Array[Int], currentIndex: Int = 1, acc: (Int, Int) = (Int.MaxValue, Int.MaxValue)): Int = {
    if (currentIndex >= arr.length - 1) acc._1 + acc._2
    else {
      val next = arr.applyOrElse(currentIndex + 1, (_: Int) => Int.MaxValue)
      val current = arr(currentIndex)
      val (firstSmallest, secondSmallest) = acc
      val min = next min current
      Array(firstSmallest, secondSmallest, min).max match {
        case value if value != min =>
          calculateCost(arr, currentIndex + 2, (min, firstSmallest min secondSmallest))
        case _ =>
          calculateCost(arr, currentIndex + 1, acc)
      }
    }
  }
```

Now I'm not totally happy with the `Array` thing and accessing by index. So I wanted to see some alternative implementation that is more Scala-ish.

Comment: Idk if I'm misunderstanding the question, but I think you could drop the first and last element of the array, add indices to the remainder, sort by value, then take the first pair in the list whose indices are not adjacent (drop the head until the first pair satisfies this condition). Those are your breakpoints.

Comment: What are the performance requirements in terms of complexity?

Comment: @stefanobaghino there's no strict requirements, I just made them up, but still I think `O(n)` both for space and time complexity would be suitable

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with accessing by index? If you want an efficient solution I think you can't do without an `IndexedSeq`. There's nothing in particular about an indexed sequence that is not Scala-ish.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin  "take the first pair in the list whose indices are not adjacent"  `[1,2,3,4,19,20,18,21]` -- what does your algorithm take?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Start with `[5, 3, 8, 2, 10932, 4, 1, 87, 1]`. Add indices: `[(0,5),(1,3),(2,8),(3,2),(4,10932),(5,4),(6,1),(7,87),(8,1)]`. Drop the first and last element: `[(1,3),(2,8),(3,2),(4,10932),(5,4),(6,1),(7,87)]`. Sort by value: `[(6,1),(3,2),(1,3),(5,4),(2,8),(7,87),(4,10932)]`. Neither of the first two elements are adjacent (|6 - 3| > 1) so you just take indices 6 and 3 and break there. If they were adjacent, you would drop the first element of this list (`(6,1)`) and try again.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I didn't ask what happens with `[5, 3, 8, 2, 10932, 4, 1, 87, 1]`, I asked what happens with `[1,2,3,4,19,20,18,21]`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. You apply an analogous process to any input you may conceive of. I leave this to you as an exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one #1:

```
def cost(ints: Seq[Int], parts: Int = 3): Int = parts match {
  case 1 => 0
  case n => ((2*n-3) until (ints.size-1)).map(i => cost(ints.take(i), parts-1) + ints(i)).min
}

scala> cost(Seq(5, 3, 8, 2, 10932, 4, 1, 87, 1), 3)
val res1: Int = 3
```

And another one #2:

```
def cost(ints: Seq[Int], parts: Int = 3): Int = 
  if (ints.size < 2*parts - 1) Int.MaxValue
  else if (parts == 1) 0
  else math.min(ints(1) + cost(ints.drop(2), parts-1), cost(ints.drop(1), parts))
```

And there is a performance one #3 (O(n) time and O(n) space):

```
def cost(ints: IndexedSeq[Int]): Int = {
  val mins = ints.tail.scanLeft(Int.MaxValue)(_ min _).tail
  (ints.slice(3, ints.size - 1) zip mins).map{ case(x, y) => x + y }.min
}
```

**Note**: Basiclly, this question is a simple DP problem. Both #1 and #2 can be easy rewrite to a performance one with O(n * (parts - 1)) time (and space).

Answer (score 1):

Not an efficient solution (both time and space are `O(n^2)`) but worth mentioning it due to its simplicity, in case you can rely on `n` being relatively small in size: lazily enumerate the cost for all index pairs such that neither is terminal nor adjacent and then pick the smallest one.

```
// assumes ns.length >= 5
def costs(ns: IndexedSeq[Int]): LazyList[Int] =
  for {
      left <- LazyList.range(1, ns.length - 4)
      right <- LazyList.range(left + 2, ns.length - 2)
  } yield ns(left) + ns(right)

assert(costs(IndexedSeq(5, 3, 8, 2, 10932, 4, 1, 87, 1)).min == 3)
assert(costs(IndexedSeq.fill(5000)(1)).min == 2)
```

Up to 1000 items the solution comes back almost immediately. With 5000 you can see the solution starting to take its time. You can play around with this [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/tm7dsPDTRDy18VoERkqK1Q/25).

Answer (score 0):

**Not going to accept this unless this is the best solution, so please share your ideas :D**

Just now I came up with the following implementation, that uses pattern matching over lists:

```scala
def calculateCost: List[Int] => Int = {
    @tailrec
    def calculateCostHelper(list: List[Int], acc: (Int, Int)): Int = {
      val (firstSmallest, secondSmallest) = acc
      list match {
        case List(preLast, _) =>
          firstSmallest + secondSmallest + preLast - Array(firstSmallest, secondSmallest, preLast).max
        case head :: tail =>
          Array(firstSmallest, secondSmallest, head).max match {
            case value if value != head =>
              calculateCostHelper(tail, (head, firstSmallest min secondSmallest))
            case _ =>
              calculateCostHelper(tail, (firstSmallest, secondSmallest))
          }
        case Nil => 0
      }
    }
      calculateCostHelper(_, (Int.MaxValue, Int.MaxValue))
  }
```

Comment: This won't work if the first element in the array is a minimum: `calculateCost(List(1, 5, 3, 8, 2, 10932, 4, 1, 87, 1)))` gets cost 2 instead of 3. I find this problem pretty tricky to do in an FP style. I don't know of any way to get the last element in a singly linked list without doing O(n) iteration. Perhaps this problem is more suitable for an Array.

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip Yeah good points! I can fix the first issue by passing the tail to the inside tailrec function, and about the second point, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

This has exponential complexity if we consider `n` as the number of parts: it does (2^n) - 1 recursive calls. But it does not have problems working with huge arrays. They return as fast as small arrays, if the number of parts remains the same.

I found it much more intuitive than the implementations seen. Practically, it finds the first minimum in the array where the first split is done, and then recursively tries to split each half as long as it still has `n > 1` (splits to do), picking the minimum cost on the way back. It resembles a *divide-and-conquer* approach.

```
  def minCost(s: Array[Int], n: Int): Int =
    if (n == 1) 0
    else if (s.length < 3) Int.MaxValue
    else {
      val (smin, idx) = s.slice(1, s.length - 1).zipWithIndex.min

      smin + math.min(
        minCost(s.take(idx + 1), n - 1),
        minCost(s.drop(idx + 2), n - 1)
      )
    }

  println(minCost(Array(5, 3, 8, 2, 10932, 4, 1, 87, 1), 4)) // 6
  println(minCost(Array(5, 3, 8, 2, 10932, 4, 1, 87, 1), 3)) // 3
  println(minCost(Array(2, 1, 3, 3, 4), 3))                  // 4
  println(minCost(Array.fill(5000000)(1), 3))                // 2
```

Also adding the resulting parts is easy: add `s` into a set on the corner cases: when `n == 1` and `s.length < 3`. Then put `minCost` inside a top-level definition, from where we define the set, call `minCost` and returns the parts set instead, or both the parts set and cost inside a tuple.

How can we do better? What does one particularly not like about the solution (besides the huge complexity)? Personally, I don't like the fact that I need to do 2 recursive calls because I don't know from which half will the next split come from, so I need to take both halves into account.

Does the problem care from which half it comes as long as the correct split is found ? No, it doesn't! That means we could theoretically combine both halves into one and just do 1 recursive call.
We just need to take into account the corner case:

I cannot do a split at 2 adjacent elements of a split - that means we can drop the 2 adjacent elements from the next recursive call, as long as the 2 adjacent elements are located *inside* the initial array, and not at the ends of it. If they are located at the ends of the initial array, I keep them because I need the bounds of the array.

I will never split at them but they are required in the array so that I can search for the next split from *within* the bounds.
This results into the next design:

```
  def minCost(s: Array[Int], n: Int): Int =
    if (n == 1) 0
    else if (s.length < 3) Int.MaxValue
    else {
      val s1          = s.slice(1, s.length - 1)
      val (smin, idx) = s1.zipWithIndex.min

      val left  = s.take(1) ++ s1.take(idx - 1)
      val right = s1.drop(idx + 2) ++ s.takeRight(1)

      smin + minCost(left ++ right, n - 1)
    }

  println(minCost(Array(5, 3, 8, 4, 10932, 2, 87, 1, 1), 4)) // 6
  println(minCost(Array(5, 3, 8, 2, 10932, 4, 1, 87, 1), 3)) // 3
  println(minCost(Array(5, 3, 8, 2, 10932, 4, 1, 87, 1), 4)) // 6
  println(minCost(Array(2, 1, 3, 3, 4), 3))                  // 4
  println(minCost(Array.fill(5000000)(1), 3))                // 2
```

I added examples with splits close to both ends of the array to test the algorithm's correctness.
In this manner, we have reduced enormously our time complexity to O(n) (where n is the number of splits - not size of the array). This is definitely an efficient solution: for example, for `n = 5`, now we'll only do 5 recursive calls, from 31 previously. Nice!